# Is it possible to echo log data to a batch script instead of a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, cmd

Basically, I want to log to an *abstraction* of a log file instead of a *concrete implementation* of a log file.

**Scenario**: I will have several job-kickoff-batch-scripts that will each kick off a particular process during the day. Windows Task Scheduler tasks will be used to trigger the batch files.

**Problem**: I don't want to echo to a log file from task scheduler (by appending a `>> C:\LogFolder\log.txt` argument) or from the job-kickoff-batch-scripts themselves (by adding `call :sub >> C:\LogFolder\log.txt`) in case the location of the log folder changes.

**Potential Solution**: Is it possible to echo log data to a `logging.bat` script instead of a log file like `log.txt`? This way, when we change how or where we log stuff, we can just change the `logging.bat` script file and not have to change any code in each one of the job-kickoff-batch-scripts themselves.

Something like this for the `job-kickoff.bat` script:

```
call :sub | logging.bat  
exit 

:sub
ECHO Some text that needs to be logged
```

And this for the `logging.bat` script:

```
ECHO %1 >> C:\LogFolder\Log.txt
```

I can't get that to work for some reason. Also, even if it works, I'm not sure if that's the best way to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly like your approach (which won't work, as you noticed), but how about:

```
call <be sure to give a complete absolute path>\logging.bat
call :sub >> %logfile%
goto :eof 

:sub
ECHO Some text that needs to be logged
```

and `logging.bat` like:

```
@set "logfile=C:\LogFolder\Log.txt"
```